# Method to add element to SetHash in Perl6

Tags: hashmap, mutable, raku, unordered, sethash

I'm just starting out with Perl6, and I'm trying to determine how to add an element to a SetHash. It seems that hash notation works, but I'm wondering if I'm missing a method that does the same thing? I'm looking at the [SetHash documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/type/SetHash), but I find it a bit opaque.

```
my $foo = SetHash.new();
$foo{'a'} = True;
'a' ∈ $foo # True;
```

Comment: I know that 'set' is a misleading tag, but without 1500 reputation, I can't create 'SetHash'

Comment: The point of SetHash is that it works like both a Set and a Hash. That is `my %foo is SetHash; %foo<a> = 32; say %foo<a>; # True` ( also why do you have a defined-or operator `//` there? )

Comment: Correct the comment. I'm new to Perl6, and lapse into using C-style comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, though what exact method SetHash should have is still up for debate.  https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=128903.

Someone else posted this as an answer, but it seems to have been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work now:

```
my $hash = SetHash.new();
$hash{'a'} = True;
say $hash, " in a ", $hash.^name;
```

Returns: `SetHash(a) in a SetHash`. So you're good to go here. The documentation might be improved, anyway. We'll do just that.